# How to set default value in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have bulk amount of data stored in SQL Server 2008. Now I want to add new field `[Book_ID]` with `default` value 1 to existing table but its not working.

**`code`**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209] (
    [Ayat_Translation_Language_ID] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Translation_Laanguage_ID]     INT            NULL,
    [Juz_ID]                       INT            NULL,
    [Surah_ID]                     INT            NOT NULL,
    [Ayat_Description]             NVARCHAR (MAX) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS NOT NULL,
    [Ayat_No]                      INT            NULL,
    [Book_ID]                      INT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Ayat_Translation_Language_ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [fkey2] FOREIGN KEY ([Translation_Laanguage_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Translation_Language] ([TransLation_Language_ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [fkey1] FOREIGN KEY ([Surah_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Surah] ([Surah_ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [fkey0] FOREIGN KEY ([Juz_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Juz] ([Juz_ID])
);
```

New field is added to table but it contains `Null`. any help!

Comment: How do you try to add the default value here? What you show is not a "add field" but a "create table" statement. What is the problem, because your syntax looks fine. Any error?

Comment: `[Book_ID] INT NULL DEFAULT 1,` remove `NULL` from this line if you want a default value.

Comment: If the column is nullable, then null will be the value used for existing rows

Comment: If you explicitly insert `NULL` into the column, it will take `NULL`, not the default. Omit column out totally during an insert if you want it to take on the default.

Comment: no error , just NUll values! @TomTom

Comment: And you are inserting that field? Defaults are not used if your INSERT is doing a null... which OR-Mappers will maybe do. It is only used if the insert statement is not even mentioning the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior depends on the way you insert data. If you explicitly insert NULL into the column, it will take NULL, not the default. Omit the `Book_ID` column out totally during an insert if you want it to take on the default (or, you can also use the keyword `DEFAULT` [as a placeholder](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac9e8/1)).

e.g. This will still insert NULL:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209] 
(
    [Ayat_Translation_Language_ID], ,
    [Translation_Laanguage_ID]     ,
    [Juz_ID]                       ,
    [Surah_ID]                     ,
    [Ayat_Description]             ,
    [Ayat_No]                      ,
    [Book_ID]                      
)
VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 'Foo', 5, NULL);
```

Whereas this will assume the default:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209] 
(
    [Ayat_Translation_Language_ID], ,
    [Translation_Laanguage_ID]     ,
    [Juz_ID]                       ,
    [Surah_ID]                     ,
    [Ayat_Description]             ,
    [Ayat_No]
    -- BOOK_ID is omitted, or use DEFAULT
)
VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 'Foo', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to now alter the table to not accept NULL for Book_ID

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209]
    ALTER COLUMN [Book_ID] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

If that gives errors, you may need to update the existing records first:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Ayyat_Translation_Language_old_20131209]
    SET [Book_ID] = 1
```